# How to extract intercept parameter from python pygam.LinearGAM

Tags: python, gam, pygam

I am looking to extract the fitted parameter from a model fit with pygam.  Here is a reproducible example.

```
from pygam import LinearGAM, s, f
from pygam.datasets import wage
X, y = wage()
gam = LinearGAM(s(0) + s(1) + f(2)).fit(X, y)
```

Here are few things I have tried.

```
#gam.summary() ## This does not show it.
#gam.intercept_ ## This does not exit.
#gam.terms.info ## This does not contain it.
#gam.partial_dependence(-1) ## This raises an error.
```

Here is a relevant GitHub issue that does not appear top have been implemented: https://github.com/dswah/pyGAM/issues/85

Comment: @jhpratt why the rollback to revision 1?

Comment: Also, why the downvote?  Lmk how I can improve the question, please.

Comment: I rolled back because I don't see a legitimate need for that tag — it appears as though you only created it so you could get rep from editing it into old questions. What advantage does it provide over the [tag:python] and [tag:gam] tags?

Comment: @jhpratt Thanks for the response.  pygam is a specific python library that exists on PyPi and Conda. A GAM, on the other hand, is a statistical model.  There are implementations of GAM models in other python libraries.  Thus, the advantage of having the pygam tag is to identify the specific Python library used to implement a GAM model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### TL;DR

- The default stores the intercept as last of the coefficients and can be extracted via `gam.coef_[-1]`.
- The `terms` attribute can be printed to verify this behavior.
- You can be more explicit by importing `pygam.intercept` and including it in your formula (e.g. `gam = LinearGAM(intercept + s(0) + s(1) + f(2)).fit(X, y)`)

### Default Behavior and Terms

The default stores the intercept as last of the coefficients and can be extracted via `gam.coef_[-1]`.  Print the `terms` attribute to verify this.

```
from pygam import LinearGAM, s, f
from pygam.datasets import wage
X, y = wage()
gam = LinearGAM(s(0) + s(1) + f(2)).fit(X, y)
print(gam.terms)
# s(0) + s(1) + f(2) + intercept
print(gam.coef_[-1])
# 96.31496573750117
```

### Explicitly declaring the intercept

It is a good idea to explicitly include the intercept in your formula so that you are not relying on the intercept being the last element of the coefficients.

```
from pygam import intercept
gam = LinearGAM(intercept + s(0) + s(1) + f(2)).fit(X, y)
print(gam.terms)
# intercept + s(0) + s(1) + f(2)
print(gam.coef_[0])
# 96.31499924945388
```